# .ToString() does not raise an exception on double? or long? while it will raise an exception on null string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three properties as follow:-

```
public Nullable<double> SPEED { get; set; }
public Nullable<Int64> PROCESSORCOUNT { get; set; }
public string CPUNAME { get; set; }
```

now inside my asp.net mvc5 web application's controller class, if i pass null for the above three variables, as follow:-

```
query["proSpeed"] = sj.SPEED.ToString();
query["proCores"] = sj.PROCESSORCOUNT.ToString();
query["proType"] = sj.CPUNAME.ToString();
```

then the toString() will only raise an exception on the null string mainly `sj.CPUNAME.ToString();`, so can anyone adivce why `ToString()` will not raise an exception if i try to convert `double?` or `long?` that contain null values to string, but it will raise a null reference exception only if the string is null  ?

Comment: But why ToString() if the variable type is string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To simplify it:

```
int? x = null;
string result = x.ToString(); // No exception
```

Here `null` isn't a null *reference*. It's just a null value of the type `int?`, i.e. a value of type `Nullable<int>` where `HasValue` is false.

You're just invoking the [`Nullable<T>.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx) method on that value. No null references are involved, so there's no `NullReferenceException`. The behaviour is documented as:

> The text representation of the value of the current `Nullable<T>` object if the `HasValue` property is true, or an empty string ("") if the `HasValue` property is false.

In other words, it's effectively implemented as:

```
return HasValue ? Value.ToString() : "";
```

Note that this only works if the *compile-time type* is the nullable type.

If you end up boxing a null value, you'll end up with a null reference:

```
object y = x;               // Oh noes, now y is a null reference...
string bang = y.ToString(); // so this throws!
```

Comment: so in your example x.ToString will return actully return empty string rather than an actual null ?

Comment: @johnG: Yup. Test it yourself - `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString().Length);`

Answer (score 1):

`Nullable<T>` cannot itself be null, its value can. For example, you could implement its `ToString` method as:

```
public string override ToString()
{
     if (this.HasValue) return this.Value;
     else return string.Empty;
}
```

You can't do the same thing for `string`, thus if the string is null, a `NullReferenceException` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN Help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx) is fairly clear on this.

> The text representation of the value of the current Nullable object
>   if the HasValue property is true, or an empty string ("") if the
>   HasValue property is false.